# ccDrawline till half of the touch location cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

My Problem is i want to draw a line which is exactly half of the touch location
i.e, i am drawing a line on cctouchesmoved and it is drawing a line from first location to my touch location but my problem is i need to display the line only till half of the touch location
here is my code

```
-(void)draw{
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glLineWidth(3.0f); // set line width       
    glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);  // set line color.      
    ccDrawLine(point1,Point2);    
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{    
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    point1 = location;
    Point2=CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you're expecting to happen and what's happening that's different from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give two points, a and b, where a is the 'origin' :

```
ccpMidPoint(a,b);
```

or, more generally, you could get an arbitrary distance along the line by subtracting a from b, multiplying by the desired factor, then re-adding a:

```
float percentageOfDistanceAlongLine = 0.5f;
CGPoint pointAlongLine = ccpMult( ccpSub(b, a), percentageOfDistanceAlongLine);
pointAlongLine = ccpAdd(a, pointAlongLine);
```

so, in your case, point2 = a, point1 = b